# How can we build charts on Polymer 1.0 using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, chart.js

I wonder if we have readily available chart elements for polymer 1.0. I am trying to migrate chart-doughnut (https://github.com/robdodson/chart-elements/) from polymer 0.5 to 1.0 which uses Chart.js script.

I have migrated the chart-doughnut.html file in following way :

```html
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="chart-js-import.html">
  
  <!--
  Pie and doughnut charts are probably the most commonly used chart there are. They are divided into segments, the arc of each segment shows a the proportional value of each piece of data.
  
  They are excellent at showing the relational proportions between data.
  
  Pie and doughnut charts in are effectively the same class in Chart.js, but have one different default value - their percentageInnerCutout. This equates what percentage of the inner should be cut out. This defaults to 0 for pie charts, and 50 for doughnuts.
  
  They are also registered under two aliases in the Chart core. Other than their different default value, and different alias, they are exactly the same.
  
  ##### Example
  
      <chart-doughnut values="[30, 50, 100, 40, 120]"></chart-doughnut>
  
  @element chart-doughnut
  @blurb A chart for showing the relational proportions between data.
  @status alpha
  @homepage http://robdodson.github.io/chart-elements
  -->
  <dom-module id="chart-doughnut">
    <template>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}"></canvas>
    </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'chart-doughnut',
      properties: {
        colors: {
          type: Array,
          value: ['#F7464A',
              '#46BFBD',
              '#FDB45C',
              '#949FB1',
              '#4D5360'
            ];
          },
          notify: true,
          observer: 'updateChart'
        },
        height: {
          notify: true,
          observer: 'resize'
        },
        options: {
          type: Object,
          value: {};
          },
          notify: true,
          observer: 'updateChart'
        },
        values: {
          type: Array,
          value: [
              30,
              50,
              100,
              40,
              120
            ];
          },
          notify: true,
          observer: 'updateChart'
        },
        width: {
          notify: true,
          observer: 'resize'
        }
      },
      resize: function () {
        if (this.chart) {
          this.updateChart();
        }
      },
      updateChart: function () {
        this.async(function () {
          if (this.chart) {
            console.log("CHARTTTT"+this.chart);
            this.chart.destroy();  // Bindings don't seem to be taking effect properly so
                                   // manually set width and height
            // Bindings don't seem to be taking effect properly so
            // manually set width and height
            this.$.canvas.setAttribute('width', this.width);
            this.$.canvas.setAttribute('height', this.height);
          }
          this.data = [];
          this.values.forEach(function (val, i) {
            this.data.push({
              color: this.colors[i],
              value: val
            });
          }, this);
          this.ctx = this.$.canvas.getContext('2d');
          this.chart = new Chart(this.ctx).Doughnut(this.data, this.options);
        }, null, 0);
      }
    });
  </script>
   </dom-module>
```

But on using it, i am getting the below error in Chart.js

> Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'arc' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The radius provided (-0.5) is negative.
>   Chart.js:1226 0   0  -0.5  4.71238898038469   4.713461589614612

pls suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart canvas doesn't have width and height when you are initializing it.

The easiest way to fix it would be to just move it into the next tick with a setTimeout.

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function() {
    self.chart = new Chart(self.ctx).Doughnut(self.data, self.options);
}, 0)
```

---

Plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/i3HrDxd5jUfTfLPVlNPg?p=preview

---

Note that if you are doing the same thing for line charts, the attributes need to be proper JSON (i.e. should use " instead of ')

```
<chart-line width="400"
            height="200"
            labels='["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]'
            values="[[10,14,20,25,13,9,40]]"
            colors='["253,180,92","247,70,74","70,191,189","148,159,177","77,83,96"]'>
</chart-line>
```

---

Plunkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/o74WRX404NWhHGiNqkC8?p=preview

Comment: Hi can we also create Area chart in similar manner? can you upload a sample project for this too?

Comment: Chart.js doesn't have area charts (it does have line charts that you can fill in though). Btw, I just copied most of the code from your question - I didn't have to change much except correct a few parentheses and ; and the setTimeout. So you were pretty much on the right track w.r.t the changes.

Comment: you are right. I meant chart-line. can you see the code here 
http://plnkr.co/edit/j2yYe1IyZ9kYFDknWB2s?p=preview

I seem to miss something here as i am not getting colors property. It fails with the error:  cannot read property 0 of null in the chart-line. Looks like colors array is set as null.

Comment: @potatopeelings I have exact same need on chart-line. can you help here?

Comment: @RoshanChhetri - you just needed the values to be proper JSON (see end of updated answer above). Apart from that I just added the setTimeout (just to be on the safe side - it seemed to work fine without it, because the draw() doesn't actually trigger any exceptions like negative value for doughnut). Cheers!

Comment: @RosAng - see the (2nd) Plnkr at the end of the updated answer above. You can copy the files from it - thanks to RoshanChhetri for most of the solution (I just patched the HTML a bit)